# Version System column and word information panel

Tags: 2010, document-library, column, word, document-info-panel

In SharePoint 2010 library I have Version system column based which shows version of the document. I want to add this column to the content type of document because I want this field to be shown in Word information field. But I cannot find this field to add to the content type.

Maybe system columns cannot be added or viewed in information panel? I can add other columns normally.

Comment: There is a [question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508229/how-can-i-include-value-of-sharepoints-version-column-in-a-word-document) that seems to have a solution. I found it with a Google search for `add sharepoint version number to word document`. What have you tried? Have you done any research at all? What have you found?

Comment: Hi, found this already, before I wrote post here. But this is quick part solution. I want the version column to be in information panel. I didn't find anything about system column, such as Version, beeing added to information panel.